# How to add parameters to request in JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have to add to **GET** method two dates selected by users.
How can I do this, with the opportunity to extract it at servlet later?

Code snippet from **jsp** page:

```
<p class="text-left">
  <strong><fmt:message key="apartments.arrival"/>:</strong> <input type="text" id="arrivaldate" name="arrivaldate"/> <br/>
  <strong><fmt:message key="apartments.depart"/>:</strong> <input type="text" id="departdate" name="departdate"/> <br/>
  <strong><fmt:message key="apartments.price"/>:</strong> ${apartment.price} <br/>
</p>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block"
                       href="<c:url value="/purchase?apartment=${apartment.id}"/>"><fmt:message key="button.book"/>
</a>
```

I have to take `arrivaldate` + `departdate`.

The date is chosen with the JQuery date picker.

I want to do the following:

- take two data values inputted by the user at JSP page
- set as a parameter to URL
- at servlet side into `doGet()` extract these two values. Better to avoid using the form, I want to put this request into `doGet()`.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the content of a full page - [apartments.jsp](http://pastebin.com/Wm3Ghq1e)

***How to solve this?***

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It is a bit confusing. Also, can you post the code for the whole form?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you need to generate the URL from the user request or from the Servlet to display it in your view (JSP)/use it in the `href` of a link(`<a>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what you want is to overwrite the method `doGet` of your `Servlet` (if you have not done that already) and retrieve the `GET`parameters as

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Stirng arrivaldate = request.getParameter("arrivaldate");
    Stirng departdate = request.getParameter("departdate");
    Stirng id = request.getParameter("apartment");
}
```

UPDATE:
Looking at your `apartments.jsp`, I figured out the problem. You are not using any form tag and your button `button.book` has the `GET` parameters hardcoded. That is why parameters other than `apartment` are not submitted.

To fix it, you are going to have to wrap the content of lines `74 to 81` with a `form` tag, like this:

```
<form action="/purchase" method="GET">
    <p class="text-left">
        <strong><fmt:message key="apartments.arrival"/>:</strong>
        <input type="text" id="arrivaldate" name="arrivaldate"/> <br/>
        <strong><fmt:message key="apartments.depart"/>:</strong>
        <input type="text" id="departdate" name="departdate"/> <br/>
        <strong><fmt:message key="apartments.price"/>:</strong> ${apartment.price} <br/>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" id="apartment" name="apartment" value="${apartment.id}"/>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You can also do this inside the JSP file in old-fashioned JSP-Tags like `<% Stirng arrivaldate = request.getParameter("arrivaldate"); %>` which should save you from creating a new `Servlet` subclass.

Comment: @Trein I tried it => `System.out.printf("arrival: %s\ndepart: %s%n", request.getParameter("arrivaldate"), request.getParameter("departdate"));` at doGet() => `arrival: null
depart: null` output to console. This approach doesn't work.

Comment: @nazar_art I pretty sure it works. Can you post the code of your HTML form?

Comment: @nazar_art I've updated the answer. Now I see why you were getting `null` at the `Servlet` side. I assumed you had a `form` on your `JSP` page.

Comment: @Trein Only this `<input type="text" id="apartment" name="apartment" value="${apartment.id}"/>` should be only plain text instead of input field.

Comment: @nazar_art Sorry for that. I've edited the `JSP` and changed the input type to `hidden` so that it will be hidden to the user, but send to the `Servlet`.

Comment: @Trein How to do it visible, but static as text? And keep having the same functionality.

Comment: @nazar_art You have to keep both. One `<input>` field type hidden and you can add another one like `<p>${apartment.id}</p>` with the that information. In order to keep the functionality, you can't remove the `<input>` field.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your example is from a JavaScript page?

If you had the following url:

```
blah.com/home?name=blah
```

You can use various languages(PHP, JavaScript, Java) to then do a `getParam("name")` which would return `blah`.

You can also look into a rest service where you can do URL params using the following URL.

```
blah.com/home/blah
```

where you have the java code something like this

```
@GET
@Path("/home/{name}")
@Produces("text/html")
public String Test(@URLParam String name) {
   return name;
}
```

Answered in Java cause question has java tag.

Comment: Actually according to JSTL tags, it seems he is using JSP and nothing tells us he has a JAX-RS backend. I think he wants a solution using JSP/Servlets.

Comment: @djc391 I fixed this misunderstanding. I need solution for jsp page, of course.

Answer (score 0):

just try this method to get your arrivaldate + departdate.

```
$("#from_date").datepicker({
    minDate   : 0,
    onSelect: function() {
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate());
        $("#to_date").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minDate);
    }
});

$("#to_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
});
```

[fiddle demo to click here.](http://jsfiddle.net/tXyLn/8/)

Comment: How will extract this variable value at servlet side?